# How to modify XML node attribute using XMLSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy

I am trying to rename the parent and child node and code something like this,

```
    def xml = (''' <resultset columns="13" rows="2">
    <row number="1">
    <enterpise>DE</enterpise>
    <line>0001</line>
    <name>DELL</name>
    <version>0.01</version>
    <updtae isnull="true"/>
    </row>
    <row number="2">
    <enterpise>DF</enterpise>
    <line>0002</line>
    <name>DELL</name>
    <version>0.01</version>
    <updtae isnull="true"/>
    </row>
    </resultset>
    ''')
def resultset = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml) 
def record = resultset.record.find{ it.@columns=='13'}.each 
{ p -> p.attributes().13('columns') } 
resultset.row.replaceNode { row { tr { td("DE") } tr { td("0001") } } }
```

The expected result is

```
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <tr><td ss:Type="String">DE</td></tr>
    <tr><td ss:Type="Number">0001</td></tr>
    <tr><td ss:Type="Sring">DELL</td></tr>
    <tr><td ss:Type="Number">0.01</td></tr>
    <tr><td ss:Type="String"></td></tr>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <tr><td ss:Type="String">DF</td></tr>
    <tr><td ss:Type="Number">0002</td></tr>
    <tr><td ss:Type="Sring">DELL</td></tr>
    <tr><td ss:Type="Number">0.01</td></tr>
    <tr><td ss:Type="String"></td></tr>
</Row>
```

I am unable to remove the parent (resultset) tag and instead of passing the value 'DE' or '0001',  i need to get it dynamically. Can you pls help me to complete this

Comment: You can use `replaceNode()`, example [here](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_modifying_removing_nodes)

Comment: I have tried something like this and able to change the node but unable to remove the parent tag(resultset).                 def resultset = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def record = resultset.record.find{ it.@columns=='13'}.each { p -> p.attributes().13('columns') }
resultset.row.replaceNode
{
    row {
        tr
          {
 td("DE")
          }
        tr
         {
         td("0001")
         }
}
}    Also instead of passing the value 'DE' or '0001',  i need to get it dynamically from row tag.  Can you please help me on this

Comment: Update your question with your code.

Comment: updated the code in the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
import groovy.xml.* 

def inData = '''
<resultset columns="13" rows="2">
   <row number="1">
     <enterpise>DE</enterpise>
     <line>0001</line>
     <name>DELL</name>
     <version>0.01</version>
     <updtae isnull="true"/>
   </row>
   <row number="2">
     <enterpise>DF</enterpise>
     <line>0002</line>
     <name>DELL</name>
     <version>0.01</version>
     <updtae isnull="true"/>
   </row>
 </resultset>'''

def inXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(inData)

def outData = new StringWriter()
def outXml = new MarkupBuilder(outData)

inXml.row.each { row -> 
  outXml.Row('ss:AutoFitHeights': 0) {
    tr { td('ss:Type': 'String', row.enterpise) }
    tr { td('ss:Type': 'Number', row.line)       }
    tr { td('ss:Type': 'String', row.name) }
    tr { td('ss:Type': 'Number', row.version) }
    tr { td('ss:Type': 'String') }
  }
}

println outData
```

when run, produces the following output:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
output:
<Row ss:AutoFitHeights='0'>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='String'>DE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='Number'>0001</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='String'>DELL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='Number'>0.01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='String' />
  </tr>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeights='0'>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='String'>DF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='Number'>0002</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='String'>DELL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='Number'>0.01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ss:Type='String' />
  </tr>
</Row>
```

which I think is pretty close to what you are trying to create. In general, if your are trying to do a transformation, not just remove a node, it is easier to create a whole new xml document as in the code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  this is what i want actually